# How to get DOM structure of matching xpath from xml structure using java/python

Tags: java, html, xml, python-3.x, xpath

Considering the below XML structure, how can i get/print the corresponding DOM structure which matches the given xpath.

```
<foo>
    <foo1>Foo Test 1</foo1>
    <foo2>
        <another1>
            <test1>Foo Test 2</test1>
        </another1>
    </foo2>
    <foo3>Foo Test 3</foo3>
    <foo4>Foo Test 4</foo4>
</foo>
```

say for xpath `/foo/foo2` the output should be something like

```
    <another1>
        <test1>Foo Test 2</test1>
    </another1>
```

Comment: Have you looked at some XPath APIs for Java? There are a lots of tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the DOM structure in the form of an xml just with xpath. With xpath and evaluate, you will get DOM nodes. You can construct the xml you want from the NODESET, but that will be cumbersome as the number of child nodes increase under the element of interest ( here it is `another1` with just one child node - it is Ok )

But otherwise consider using XSLT like below :

NOTE : I have used xslt as a string, this is Ok if your requirement is as simple as just show `another1`, otherwise you need to create a new `.xsl` file and use that to create `StreamSource` like : `new StreamSource( new File("mystylesheet.xsl") )`

```
String xslt = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                    "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">" +
                    "<xsl:output method=\"xml\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\"/>" +
                    "<xsl:template match=\"/\">" +
                    "<xsl:copy-of select=\"//foo/foo2/another1\"/>" +
                    "</xsl:template>" +
                    "</xsl:stylesheet>";



Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer( new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)) );
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource( new File( "anotherfoo.xml" ) );
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(sw) );

System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

The way it works is the transfomer applies the XSLT string on your xml ( denoted by `anotherfoo.xml` in the code above ) and gets the elements that matches the xpath `//foo/foo2/another1` through `xsl:copy-of`.